# Input/References on time series modeling/prediction without assuming stationarity

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references, stationarity, methodology

I am trying to find out what methodologies there are for analyzing/modeling time series without assuming the time series is stationary/trying to make the time series stationary. I am wanting to do this to explore if there is some form of useful information that is being discarded when traditional approaches to approximating stationarity are applied such as differencing, etc.

When attempting to search for frameworks that don't assume stationarity through terms such as "Non-stationary time series modeling" or "Non-stationary time series forecasting", aside from the common approaches such as exponential smoothing and time series distance clustering, I tend to run into approaches that start with non-stationary data, attempt to approximate stationarity, then apply methods that assume stationarity.

I am looking for any input/references/search terms that may point me more towards what I have in mind.

Comment: Try exponential smoothing, most other state space models, TBATS and many others. See https://OTexts.com/fpp3 for a reference.

Comment: I'm not a fan of exponential smoothing. -- it's mostly guesswork which loses too much information. This book is probably a go-to -- *Non-linear and non-stationary time series analysis* https://www.google.com/books/edition/Non_linear_and_Non_stationary_Time_Serie/8xbvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=Non-linear%20and%20non-stationary%20time%20series%20analysis

Comment: Thank you for the references/terms, @RobHyndman! I've looked into exponential smoothing some and state space models a bit, but I'll have to dig deeper. Also, your text on time series modeling has been really helpful as reference, so thank you! and again, I'll have to piece through that more, too :)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, @MikeHunter, this looks interesting and I'll have to see if I can get access to this book :) Would you mind expounding a bit on why you say that exponential smoothing is "mostly guesswork" and that it "loses too much information"?

Comment: The guesswork involves the choice of smoothing parameter, i.e., how much do you want the past to influence the present. In other words, there is no theoretical basis for the choice of smoothing parameter. The loss of information is implicit in any smoothing method -- whether exponential, rolling averages, etc. -- since they blunt and erase time specific volatility, information which can be quite useful depending on the analysis. I have a similar grudge against outlier elimination, a naive and ubiquitous source of thousands of queries on this site.

Comment: @MikeHunter This seems about 25 years out of date. See my Springer book for the theoretical basis for exponential smoothing.

Comment: @RobHyndman Thank you for your comment. Having browsed through your link, I see how it differs from the work done over the years prior to your pub with the introduction of information-based metrics such as the AIC, AICc and BIC. These are indeed significant contributions making the guesswork in choice of smoothing parameter an empirically driven choice, correct? Empirical choices motivate theoretical hurdles but are they equivalent? No, imo. Second, my point wrt how all smoothing methodologies blunt and erase useful volatility is not changed by your book.

Comment: Just to be clear on the distinction between *theoretical* vs *empirical* predictions, consider Peter Higgs' theoretically motivated prediction of the boson. It took nearly fifty years before it was confirmed. On the other hand, empirical confirmation of a prediction is based on choice from a set of best-performing metric(s) and, therefore, meet a much lower scientific standard.